# Sklearn: Should I create a MinMaxScaler for the target and one for the input?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, scikit-learn, normalization, scales

Suppose I have some input data `X` with shape `[n,m]`.
I also have some target data `y` with shape `[s,p]`.

I want to train a model with some train data and then compare the results on the test data, as usual. I came across the idea of normalizing the data. However, I don't understand (although the documentation is pretty good [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)) whether I should use one min max scaler for the input and one for the ouput or just one? Also, should I apply it on the training set only right? Not training + test?

**SCALER FOR X_TRAIN, SCALER FOR Y_TRAIN**

```
# divide into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, shuffle = False, tests_size = 0.33)
# create scalers
scalerX = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scalery = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
# fit and transform
X_train = scalerX.fit_transform(X_train)
y_y_train = scalery.fit_transform(y_train)
X_test = scalerX.transform(X_test)
y_test = scalery.transform(y_test)
# then once I will have the predictions
y_pred = scalery.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

**SCALER FOR X , SCALER FOR Y**

```
scalerX = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaley = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
X = scalerX.fit_transform(X)
y = scalery.fit_transform(y)
# training and testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, shuffle = False, test_size = 0.33)
# then once I will have the predictions
y_pred = scalery.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

**ONE SCALER FOR XY MATRIX**

```
Xy = np.hstack((X, y))
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
Xy = scaler.fit_transform(Xy)
# then separate training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xy,shuffle = False, test_size = 0.33)
# once I will have the predictions
y_pred = scaler.transform(y_pred)
```

Which one of these three options is the correct one? Or are they all wrong?

Comment: There's an error in the last part. train_test_split(Xy,shuffle = False, test_size = 0.33) returns two arrays, not four. Perhaps you should split Xy to X and y?

Answer (score 2):

Use a single scaler, fit on the train set. It's best to pretend that you are in production, and don't actually *have* the test dataset. If you fit a separate scaler, you are using information you shouldn't have.

Comment: Exactly what I thought! In reality one wouldn't have the test set.

Just to confirm, should I use it ONLY ONE SCALER on `np.hstack((X_train, y_train)) or should I use one scaler for X_train and one for y_train?

Comment: only one scaler. If you are worried that some values might be e.g. over 1 in the test set, and the model depends on the values being lower than 1, set the limits of the scaler perhaps at 0.05, 0.95.

Comment: it raises an error for the shape when I try converting the predictions..

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (5,) (2,2)

Comment: basically I used `X` with shape `[5,3]` and `y` with shape `[5,2]`. Thus I divided into training and testing set with `X_train` with shape `[3,3]` , `y_train` with shape `[3,2]` and `X_test` with shape `[2,3]` and `y_test` with shape `[2,2]`

Comment: you are making a mistake somewhere. This works:


    import numpy as np

    X_train = np.random.randn(5, 3)

    X_test = np.random.randn(3, 3)

    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

    scaler = MinMaxScaler()

    scaler.fit(X_train)

    scaler.transform(X_test)

Comment: yes that works. The problem is when trying to do the inverse scaling

Comment: if you want to inverse scale the prediction

Comment: or you can just try inverse scaling the y_test

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but maybe my answer will help some one else looking for the answer like I did.

To make this short, It does not matter if you use 2 individual scalers for X and y or if you scale the whole dataset(X and y) with 1 scaler.

Both will be scaled the same to the exact same vale.

So if you want to easily inverse transform only the target value, then I would recommend using 2 scalers, one for X and one for y

And like some comments already mentioned, your scaler should be fitted using only the training data.

Therefore, I would implement it like **SCALER FOR X_TRAIN, SCALER FOR Y_TRAIN**

If you use **ONE SCALER FOR XY MATRIX**, then you have to include some X values to re-scale, otherwise it won't work